# Why does my call to querySelectorAll('.select') return null?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a file that is responsible for all interactions with inputs. In the case below I have events linked to the two selection fields, however, in the input control file there is not only the select, there are several other inputs. So when I call this file it's shown on the console that several variables are null due to the fact that they don't exist on the current page. Let me give an example:

HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="select">
      <option value="value1">Apple</option>
      <option value="value2">Banana</option>
      <option value="value3">Grape</option>
    </select>

 <select name="select">
      <option value="value3">Bread</option>
      <option value="value4">Water</option>
      <option value="value5">Wine</option>
  </select>

<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript">
</body>
</html>
```

Input control file (script.js):

```js
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('.select');
let radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.radio');
let checkbox =  document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
```

Errors:

- Uncaught TypeError: radioInputs is null
- Uncaught TypeError: checkbox is null

How can I get around this error?

Comment: Your `querySelectorAll` is looking for classes that don't exist in your code

Comment: You also don't have any radio/checkbox inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You elements *do* exist because the script tag comes *after* the elements. That's not the problem.

Your problem is here:

```
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('.select');
let radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.radio');
let checkbox =  document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
```

The `.` prefix on `.select` looks for elements that have a *class* of `select` (for example `<div class="select">`), but you have a *tag name* that is is `select` (for example `<select>`) and no classes at all.

Remove the `.` from the selector strings and it should work as you expect:

```
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
let radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
let checkbox =  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
```

Note that radio buttons `<input type="radio">`  and check boxes `<input type="checkbox">` are both `input` tags with a different `type attribute. So to select those you have to use a different query.

Comment: There are no `radio` or `checkbox` elements so this code will fail.

Comment: Indeed, @Andy. I've updated my answer with better selectors.

Comment: @AlexWayne my answer below crossed timewise with your edit of your nice answer - same thought at same time.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to nice answer from @Alex Wayne:

Selector for 'radio' would be `input[type=radio]`
Selector for 'checkbox' would be `input[type=checkbox]`

Hence:

```js
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
let radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
let checkbox =  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
```

If I understand correctly, you just want to make sure that certain elements exist in your DOM before applying further commands (avoiding error message if there is no radio or checkbox).

Maybe, you can add following validation to your **input control file**, checking first if the type of DOM element exists:

```js
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
let radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
let checkbox =  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

console.log('selects: ' + selects.length);
console.log('radioInputs: ' + radioInputs.length);
console.log('checkbox: ' + checkbox.length);

if (selects.length > 0)  {
  // do something now, as <select> exist
}
if (radioInputs.length > 0)  {
  // do something now, as <input type='radio'> exist
}
if (checkbox.length > 0)  {
  // do something now, as <input type='checkbox'> exist
}
```

```html
<select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Apple</option>
  <option value="value2">Banana</option>
  <option value="value3">Grape</option>
</select>

<select name="select">
    <option value="value3">Bread</option>
    <option value="value4">Water</option>
    <option value="value5">Wine</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
let radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('radio');
let checkbox =  document.querySelectorAll('checkbox');
```

remove the ".". The code you wrote was trying to look for dom elements with those specified classes(.select, .radio, .checkbox)

Comment: It still won't find radio and checkbox elements though.